# Not receiving emails sent from contact form

Tags: joomla-3.6, emails, contact, contact-form

I am running Joomla hosted on a server with **sendmail** installed.

1. The PHP mail and sendmail are working perfectly; I tested them.
2. The configuration for the mail in Joomla is correct (the info in which you can navigate by going to Site -> Server).
3. The contact info is correct -- the email domain is the same as the site domain.
4. I tried setting "custom reply" to "No".
5. I tried using "List all contact categories" and "Single contact".

However, I can't make the contact form work. I'm not receiving any emails despite a message that says it has been sent succesfully.

Comment: What extension do you use for your contact form? Breezing Form, RSForm? You can test your settings by creating a new user. Fill out an email address you can check. When saving the user an email is send to it's address. If you receive the message you know it's not Joomla or server, but your extension.

Comment: Update your form extension to the most recent version - starting at 3.5.1 Joomla made a tweak regarding "reply-to" vs "reply" and so far I've found both Breezing Forms and RSPro needed an update to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

For contact forms, I ended up using **RSJoomla Pro** to do this. It makes building the form easy and it handles the e-mail issues too.

Also, contact support with your web hosting service and verify the settings in the Global Configurations, because sometimes they change the port or other options and then need to be tweaked in order to get e-mail to work properly.

Comment: We are hosting the site on our own server.

Answer (score 0):

Though you state that PHP mail is tested and working outside of Joomla!, my suggestion would be to use the SMTP method. You can use the SMTP info of any email account you have that accepts SMTP connections (most all do). If you receive the message with the SMTP method, then you know it is a PHP mail issue.

If you still don't receive the message, then it very well could be an issue with the template you are using doing an override of the com_contact component. As such, other components/plugins/modules could be causing scripting conflicts, preventing the message from being sent.

To check to ensure the message is reaching the server for sending, check the "Mail Delivery Reports" on your server to ensure that Joomla! is actually getting the message through to EXIM.

---

Note: Many servers (especially shared servers) block the PHP mail function, so it could be the case that your host does that in the future without warning to prevent abuse. SMTP relays are fairly cheap ([Mandrill used to be free!](http://blog.mandrill.com/important-changes-to-mandrill.html)). If mail is a mission-critical part of your site, invest in a good SMTP relay service that can monitor every message sent and give you analytics for review.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this problem is caused by one of the following:

- Some wrong mail definitions at the server level
- SPF not set, or SPF set but doesn't include the IP of your server

For the first one, it is a good idea to check with your host as there are many issues that might be causing the problem.

For the second one, check your environment (cPanel/Plesk/etc...) to see how to add your SPF records.

If all else fails, check your mail logs to see what is going on.